# When Child process calls a function lost output

Tags: c

```
int handleCommand(char *command) {
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0) {
        sleep(0.5);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        execCommand(command);
        //strcat(path[0], command);
        //printf("%s", path[0]);
        //execve(path[0], path, NULL);
        //printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("ERROR");
    }

}

int execCommand(char *command) {

    char* path[] = {"/bin/", NULL};
    printf("in execCommand > %s", command );
    strcat(path[0], command);
    execve(path[0], path, NULL);
    printf("\n");
}
```

at first as you can see i put the code directly in the function where the fork takes place.  This would display the output expected when executing the ls command for example.  But when I moved this to a function i no longer see any output.

Comment: The `execCommand()` function should be of type 'function returning `void`' since it does not return any value.  It should probably print an error message and exit with a non-zero status if the `execve()` fails.  Similarly, the `handleCommand()` function does not return a value so it should be of type 'function returning `void`' too.  Also note that error messages are conventionally printed to `stderr` and not `stdout` - and for good reason.

Comment: shell.c:43: error: conflicting types for 'handleCommand'
shell.c:38: error: previous implicit declaration of 'handleCommand' was here

Comment: Those are the error messages I get when i try and make handleCommand type void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the `printf()` operations after the `execve()` are never executed if the command is executed - `execve()` only returns on error, never on success.

Next, unless you include a newline at the end of the output, the print won't be flushed to the terminal that is standard output (and there are circumstances, such as piping the standard output to another program, where even a newline is not necessarily sufficient to flush standard output).  So, you should include a newline in the message, and still do `fflush(stdout);` before the `execve()`.

Comment: Oh, and make suer you don't fall out of the fork() block even if execve fails or else everybody gets confused.